# JSTL: c:if Not Found in Build Path

Tags: maven, jsp, jstl, maven-3

I recently migrated an ANT project to Maven. After doing all the dependecnies and getting the project error free. I see this warning on in Eclipse:

```
The tag handler class for "c:if" (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag) was not found on the Java Build Path
```

I see the same warnings for c:import, c:out c:set as well.

I do have the tag:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

added in the JSP. And I have the JSTL 1.2 dependency added in the pom file. Can you tell me how to get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.  To fix it, I just added and saved the following in my pom.xml.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In some older Eclipse versions, you may need to modify the "<c:if..." line of code, remove a character or more, save it then put it back as it was and save the file again. This in some case get rid of the warning.

My code used <c:set and <c:if as the following example. No warning displays. Perhaps, you may need to update your Eclipse. My Eclipse is IDE for Enterprise Java Developers Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0).

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<%@ attribute name="normalPrice" fragment="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="onSale" fragment="true" %>
<%@ variable name-given="name" %>
<%@ variable name-given="price" %>
<%@ variable name-given="origPrice" %>
<%@ variable name-given="salePrice" %>
   <head>
      <title>Tag Example</title>
   </head>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <c:set var="name" value="Hand-held Color PDA"/>
      <c:set var="price" value="$298.86"/>
      <jsp:invoke fragment="normalPrice"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <c:set var="name" value="4-Pack 150 Watt Light Bulbs"/>
      <c:set var="origPrice" value="$2.98"/>
      <c:set var="salePrice" value="$2.32"/>
      <jsp:invoke fragment="onSale"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <c:set var="name" value="Digital Cellular Phone"/>
      <c:set var="price" value="$68.74"/>
      <jsp:invoke fragment="normalPrice"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <c:set var="name" value="Baby Grand Piano"/>
      <c:set var="price" value="$10,800.00"/>
      <jsp:invoke fragment="normalPrice"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <c:set var="name" value="Luxury Car w/ Leather Seats"/>
      <c:set var="origPrice" value="$23,980.00"/>
      <c:set var="salePrice" value="$21,070.00"/>
      <jsp:invoke fragment="onSale"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<body>
   <c:set var = "salary" scope = "session" value = "${2000*2}"/>
   <c:if test = "${salary > 2000}">
       <p>My salary is:  <c:out value = "${salary}"/><p>
   </c:if>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tag works actually fine, it is just a false negative from Eclipse. In that case you could force a new check editing the tag name and then setting it back to the right name.

So, for instance, click on your "c:if" tag, remove a single character and then re-enter it (exactly as it was before). Save it. In my case that was enough to get rid of the warning.

Comment: can you please show your solution in a short example based on question OP. It keeps your answer away from getting flagged for removal due to low quality.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24914236)

Comment: Sorry guys, I added a couple of lines to restate in another way the same concept. I have no idea how I can clarify better the solution. I had the same problem a few times and, at least in my case, the solution was that pretty simple. Just rename the tag to its name. I know it looks pretty strange, but that's it.